# PHP and the Command Line

Tags: php

I am trying to use SQLMap.py with PHP by running DOS commands using PHP.

When I run my program, `exec("python2 sqlmap.py -u 'http://public_ip:80/HackThisSite')`, my command runs correctly, but automatically quits once the first cmd user input is given. I think pasting the output should make it clearer

```
___ ___| |_____ ___ ___ {1.0-dev-nongit-20151019}
|_ -| . | | | .'| . |
|___|_ |_|_|_|_|__,| _|
|_| |_| http://sqlmap.org

[!] legal disclaimer: Usage of sqlmap for attacking targets without prior mutual consent is illegal. It is the end user's responsibility to obey all applicable local, state and federal laws. Developers assume no liability and are not responsible for any misuse or damage caused by this program

    [*] starting at 11:36:32

    [11:36:32] [WARNING] you've provided target URL without any GET parameters (e.g. www.site.com/article.php?id=1) and without providing any POST parameters through --data option
    do you want to try URI injections in the target URL itself? [Y/n/q]
    [11:36:32] [ERROR] user quit
```

Can I prevent the automatic quit of cmd from PHP and respond to the user prompt? Thanks!

P.S. I know I didn't provide GET parameters in my link, so please don't mention that in your answer. The link I used in the command is merely a test and I am soon going to use POST data with the `--data` option later.

Comment: The python script is expecting input from the user, but `exec()` is not providing it.  Does the script have flags to set those options?

Comment: I am not sure, I looked at the [PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for the function but could not find a way to add flags based on whatever I could understand.

Comment: You can find all the command-line options to `sqlmap.py` [here](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage). Why are you trying to use the tool without providing any URL parameters in the first place? That will prevent it from asking the question.

Comment: If you want to supply input to a shell command, you have to use `popen()`, not `exec`.

Comment: Yes, but the program will ask more questions later on anyways. I know pretty well how to use `sqlmap.py` and have done it successfully on my local machine. However, I am trying to run this command from a remote system using Apache server and FileZilla

Comment: @Barmar I do not know what the inputs will be...

Comment: The input should be `y` if you really want to test the URL without any parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92752/discussion-between-ytpillai-and-barmar).

Comment: OK, if I use a GET site which I have already parsed it will work. But what if I want to work with a google dork request (`-g "some_dork"` gives me a response if I want to test every site it finds)